# How can I get binary data in physical memory (windows)(c language)

Tags: c, memory

For example, in windbg, i can see some data like this image.
[image]

Could I get this data of specific address (like fffff806 701ca7e0)

Comment: Just read the memory normally, but be aware that you cannot read from an arbitrary memory location, you can only read memory owned by your process. Read about _virtual memory_.

Comment: Do you want physical memory or virtual memory? You ask for the former, but windbg gives you the latter.